# Covid restrictions on transiting through Spain from US to Turkey

Tags: usa, transit, covid-19, spain, moldovan-citizens

I'm a Moldova citizen(with F-1 visa) travelling from US to Turkey through Spain. There are no visa requirements for transiting EU and visiting Turkey. Unclearness of covid restrictions is bothering me.

> Can I transit through Spain if I get the covid test?

Also is it still called transit if I change the airplanes at the same airport? Where should I address/take a call to get answers?

UPD:

According to this file (https://data.consilium.europa.eu/doc/document/ST-9208-2020-INIT/en/pdf):

> In addition, essential travel should be allowed for the specific categories of travellers with an  essential  function  or  need  referred  to  in  Annex  II.17Member  States  may  introduce additional  safety  measures  for  these  travellers,  especially  when  their  trip  originates  in  a high risk region.

...

> Annex II. Specific categories of travellers with an essential function or need:

...

> vi.Passengers in transit

Comment: Are both legs of your journey booked as one trip (one PNR) or will you need to clear Immigration on arrival in Spain to connect to your next flight? When are you intending to travel?

Comment: What is the date of your travel? I'm in Spain and here we cannot move between regions unless it's absolutely necessary (work, medical issues, etc). BUT the restrictions are going to change the 9th of May and nobody knows if you'll be able to move between regions or not. In principle if you arrive for tourism you'll have to stay in the region your first flight ticket arrives (what @Traveller asked is very relevant).

Comment: @Traveller I'm about to buy two tickets from different avialines. It will be in the same airport and there will be several waiting hours between them. The tickets are for 25-26th May

Comment: @Ivan I'm not changing the regions, even the airport.

Comment: Will your change of airline mean you will not be able to transit airside? Typically two separate flight bookings from different airlines mean you will need to clear Immigration, collect your baggage and go through security to get to your subsequent flight, unless the two airlines have a transfer agreement

Comment: @Traveller I don't know. It is a possibility. But I'm still in Spain for transit, right? Whom should I contact to get a precise info?

Comment: #Mihail In this case you won't have any problem. A lot of tourist are arriving to Spain every day (with covid test in the last 72 hours). Anyway, you should ask the airline some days before your flight to get precise instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with covid test you should be OK to transit the Spain. You can check the details here:
https://covid19travel.com/#Spain

Comment: I'd like to buy two different tickets(as it is twice cheaper than a connected flight) so I might need to go through customs and pick my baggage. Is it still a transit area if I remain in the airport but pass through customs and visa/passport check? Do I call an airport to get an info about that?

Comment: You will/would need a full Schengen visa for that, it is not a transit area thing. Better pay the higher fee, even better, find a direct flight.

Comment: @Willeke Moldova citizens don't need to apply for any visa. It is only a question of covid restrictions. Also two not connected tickets cost 400$ while a connected ticket is about 1k$.

Comment: @Willeke Alright, I have found a connected ticket for 600$ through Frankfurt. I will call Madrid airport tomorrow and if I don't get a satisfactory answer, then I will stick to the connected ticket.